# matrix throws "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup"

Tags: tikz-matrix

I have a simple `matrix` like this

```
\matrix
{
16 & 3 & 2 & 13 \\
5 & 10 &|[fill=yellow]| 11 & 8 \\
9 & 6 + 2 & 7 & 12 \\
4 & 15 & 14 & 1 \\
};
```

My issue is the `|[fill=yellow]|` which causes the error to appear. Likely there is some conflict with another package (and I use quite some). So, any idea or pointer whether there are know issues with the matrix package and this error? Or is there any alternative to highlight cells in a matrix in a different way?

Comment: Comment out half of your packages.  Does the error stay, or go away?  Continue until you have identified the conflicting package.  Then you can post the additional 10 lines of code to turn this into a minimal working example.

Comment: @Teepeemm Haha. I said "I use quite some" because I use quite some. This would not just make my day.

Comment: You may want to use `\matrix[matrix of nodes]` instead of `\matrix`, and load the `matrix` library, of course.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Teepeemm Admittedly, I had to go through the pain... and found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as this code is it good for you, using `circledsteps` package?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{circledsteps}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/inner color=black}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/outer color=yellow}
\pgfkeys{/csteps/fill color=yellow}
$\begin{matrix}
     16 & 3 & 2 & 13 \\
5 & 10 & \Circled{11} & 8 \\
9 & 6 + 2 & 7 & 12 \\
4 & 15 & 14 & 1 
\end{matrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that might fix it. Btw. I found the cause. There was a `|` redefinition in `\lstMakeShortInline` from the `listings` package. So I have to die either way or the other ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As for someone running onto the same issue: The cause was a line like

```
\lstMakeShortInline[
  language=CSharp,
  columns=fixed,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
  ,columns=fixed]| % <- that's the cause!

  \lstnewenvironment{lstcs}
  {\lstset{
      language=CSharp,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      breaklines=true,
      columns=fullflexible
  }}
{}
```

which is something from the `listings` package (my guess, since I did not work on that part of the LaTeX source). This re-defines the `|` char and makes matrix croak.